# Get an Exception when i using the Smack to build a java web project

Tags: java, smack

I'm using smack API and openfire server to build a java IM software.And when i'm building the java code.the Console come up with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.getVersion(SmackConfiguration.java:96)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<clinit>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:38)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: could not load any factory class (even small or full default implementation); nested exception is: 
    org.kxml2.io.XmlReader
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:119)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: could not load any factory class (even small or full default implementation); nested exception is: 
    org.kxml2.io.XmlReader
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:225)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:76)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:153)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:148)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:116)
    ... 3 more
```

My Code is like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
    configBuilder.setResource("SomeResource");
    configBuilder.setServiceName("172.29.41.168");
    AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    // Connect to the server
    try {
        connection.connect();
        connection.login();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }
}
```

I already import the xmlpull_1_0_5.jar,how can i do to solve the problem?

Comment: to me works with: xmlpull-xpp3-3.0.0.20130526.jar get it a try

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks a bit like your dependencies might not be correctly setup.
So look less at your java code and more into the pom or other build files.